# libpnet error: thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value' on using tcp_header.set_options()

Tags: rust, panic, unwrap

I recently started to learn Rust and i'm trying out libpnet([github](https://github.com/libpnet/libpnet), [crates](https://crates.io/crates/pnet)). But after creating the code to build and Ethernet, IP and TCP header I stumbled upon an issue. It seems that adding `tcp_header.set_options()` results in a panic.

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pnet_packet-0.30.0/src/tcp.rs:59:1
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/1.61.0/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/1.61.0/library/core/src/panicking.rs:143:14
   2: core::panicking::panic
             at /rustc/1.61.0/library/core/src/panicking.rs:48:5
   3: core::option::Option<T>::unwrap
             at /rustc/1.61.0/library/core/src/option.rs:755:21
   4: pnet_packet::tcp::MutableTcpPacket::set_options
             at /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pnet_packet-0.30.0/src/tcp.rs:59:1
   5: scanner::tcp::build_tcp_header
             at ./src/tcp/mod.rs:86:5
   6: scanner::tcp::new_packet
             at ./src/tcp/mod.rs:26:22
   7: scanner::main
             at ./src/main.rs:32:22
   8: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/1.61.0/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:227:5
```

Running the code without adding the set_options() results the TCP packet being build and able to send. I'm not sure if this is the result of an error in my implementation or a bug in the library. I'm using `pnet = "0.30.0"`

*./main.rs*

```
use pnet::datalink::interfaces;
use pnet::datalink::Channel;
use pnet::packet::Packet;
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;
use std::str::FromStr;

mod tcp;

fn main() {
    // get interfaces
    let all_interfaces = interfaces();
    let interfaces = all_interfaces
        .iter()
        .find(|e| e.is_up() && !e.is_loopback() && !e.ips.is_empty());

    match interfaces {
        Some(interface) => println!(
            "Interface name: {}\nInterface MAC : {}\nInterface IP  : {}\n",
            interface.name,
            interface.mac.unwrap(),
            interface.ips[0]
        ),
        None => println!("Error while finding the default interface."),
    }

    let if_name = &interfaces.unwrap().name;
    let if_mac = interfaces.unwrap().mac.unwrap();
    let if_ip = interfaces.unwrap().ips[0];

    let dst_ip = Ipv4Addr::from_str("10.0.0.2").unwrap();
    let src_ip = Ipv4Addr::from_str("10.0.0.90").unwrap();
    let new_packet = tcp::new_packet(&dst_ip, &src_ip, &if_mac);

    let (mut sender, mut receiver) =
        match pnet::datalink::channel(&interfaces.unwrap(), Default::default()) {
            Ok(Channel::Ethernet(tx, rx)) => (tx, rx),
            Ok(_) => panic!("Unknown channel type"),
            Err(e) => panic!("Error happened {}", e),
        };
    let ethernet_packet = new_packet.packet();
    sender.send_to(ethernet_packet, None).unwrap().unwrap();

    if let Ok(packet) = receiver.next() {
        // match packet.get_flags() {
        //     18 => println!("open"),
        //     _ => println!("closed"),
        // }
    }
}
```

*./tcp/mod.rs*

```
use pnet::packet::ethernet::EtherTypes;
use pnet::packet::ethernet::EthernetPacket;
use pnet::packet::ethernet::MutableEthernetPacket;
use pnet::packet::ip::IpNextHeaderProtocols;
use pnet::packet::ipv4::checksum;
use pnet::packet::ipv4::Ipv4Flags;
use pnet::packet::ipv4::MutableIpv4Packet;
use pnet::packet::tcp::ipv4_checksum;
use pnet::packet::tcp::MutableTcpPacket;
use pnet::packet::tcp::TcpFlags;
use pnet::packet::tcp::TcpOption;
use pnet::packet::Packet;
use pnet::util::MacAddr;
use rand::Rng;
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;

const ETHERNET_HEADER_LEN: usize = 14;
const IPV4_HEADER_LEN: usize = 24;
const TCP_HEADER_LEN: usize = 20;

pub fn new_packet<'a>(
    dst_ip: &'a Ipv4Addr,
    src_ip: &'a Ipv4Addr,
    if_mac: &'a MacAddr,
) -> EthernetPacket<'a> {
    let tcp_header = build_tcp_header(8006, src_ip, dst_ip);
    let ipv4_header = build_ipv4_header(tcp_header, src_ip, dst_ip);
    let packet = build_ethernet_header(ipv4_header, if_mac);
    packet.consume_to_immutable()
}

fn build_ethernet_header<'a>(
    payload: MutableIpv4Packet,
    if_mac: &'a MacAddr,
) -> MutableEthernetPacket<'a> {
    let buff: Vec<u8> = vec![0; ETHERNET_HEADER_LEN + IPV4_HEADER_LEN + TCP_HEADER_LEN];
    let mut ethernet_header = MutableEthernetPacket::owned(buff).unwrap();
    ethernet_header.set_destination(MacAddr::broadcast());
    ethernet_header.set_source(*if_mac);
    ethernet_header.set_ethertype(EtherTypes::Ipv4);
    ethernet_header.set_payload(payload.to_immutable().packet()); // Concat protocol payload with ip  header
    println!("{}", format!("{ethernet_header:?}"));
    ethernet_header
}

fn build_ipv4_header<'a>(
    payload: MutableTcpPacket,
    src_ip: &'a Ipv4Addr,
    dst_ip: &'a Ipv4Addr,
) -> MutableIpv4Packet<'a> {
    let buff: Vec<u8> = vec![0; IPV4_HEADER_LEN + TCP_HEADER_LEN];
    let mut ipv4_header = MutableIpv4Packet::owned(buff).unwrap();
    ipv4_header.set_version(4); // IP header Version
    ipv4_header.set_header_length(6); // IP header Lenght
    ipv4_header.set_dscp(0); // IP header Differentiated Services Code Point
    ipv4_header.set_ecn(0); // IP header Explicit Congestion Notification
    ipv4_header.set_total_length(u16::try_from(IPV4_HEADER_LEN + TCP_HEADER_LEN).unwrap()); // IP header total length
    ipv4_header.set_flags(Ipv4Flags::DontFragment); // IP header Flags
    ipv4_header.set_fragment_offset(0); // IP header Fragmentation offset
    ipv4_header.set_ttl(255); // IP header Time To Live
    ipv4_header.set_next_level_protocol(IpNextHeaderProtocols::Tcp); // IP header Protocol
    ipv4_header.set_source(*src_ip); // IP header Source IP address
    ipv4_header.set_destination(*dst_ip); // IP header Destination IP address
    ipv4_header.set_checksum(checksum(&ipv4_header.to_immutable())); // IP header Checksum
    println!("{}", format!("{ipv4_header:?}"));
    ipv4_header.set_payload(payload.to_immutable().packet()); // Concat protocol payload with tcp header
    ipv4_header
}

fn build_tcp_header<'a>(
    dest: u16,
    src_ip: &'a Ipv4Addr,
    dst_ip: &'a Ipv4Addr,
) -> MutableTcpPacket<'a> {
    let buff: Vec<u8> = vec![0; TCP_HEADER_LEN];
    let mut tcp_header = MutableTcpPacket::owned(buff).unwrap();
    tcp_header.set_source(12345); // TCP header source port
    tcp_header.set_destination(dest); // TCP header destination port
    tcp_header.set_sequence(rand::thread_rng().gen::<u32>()); // TCP header sequence number
    tcp_header.set_acknowledgement(0); // TCP header acknowledgement number
    tcp_header.set_data_offset(8); // TCP header data offset
    tcp_header.set_reserved(0); // TCP header reserved
    tcp_header.set_flags(TcpFlags::SYN); // TCP header flags
    tcp_header.set_window(64240); // TCP header window size
    tcp_header.set_urgent_ptr(0); // TCP header urgent
    tcp_header.set_options(&[   // <----- panic <----- panic  <----- panic 
        TcpOption::mss(1460),
        TcpOption::sack_perm(),
        TcpOption::nop(),
        TcpOption::nop(),
        TcpOption::wscale(7),
    ]);
    tcp_header.set_checksum(ipv4_checksum(&tcp_header.to_immutable(), src_ip, dst_ip));
    println!("{}", format!("{tcp_header:?}"));
    tcp_header
}
```

Comment: You can only set TCP options if there is space in the header for them.  Increase the `data_offset` to accommodate the options you intend to include.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solved the problem. I haven't changed the TCP data offset value yet, but i increased the `TCP_HEADER_LEN` to 30 and now the panic is gone. I'm going to have to count my bytes to see how big it becomes and adjust the values as needed.